# UI does not update after Face Book request...why?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, textview

I am trying to set text in `TextView` `userEmail`, after calling FaceBook request for getting Email.

```
 public TextView userEmail;

          @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_profile);


                //user_profile_name
                userName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
                userEmail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user_profile_short_bio);
                userbday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_bday);
        getMyFBProfileRequest();
    }


     public void  getMyFBProfileRequest() {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        // Application code
                        try {
                            Log.i("Response",response.toString());
                             Toast.makeText(MyProfileActivity.this,object.getString("email") ,
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            // Application code
                            String email = object.getString("email");
                            String birthday = object.getString("birthday");


                            userEmail.setText(email);



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.i("Error","");
                            //profileView.showToast("Error");
                        }
                    }
                });

        // GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback objectCallback = new JSONObjectCallback();
        //  GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, objectCallback);
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "email,name,first_name,last_name,gender");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }
```

And I get a fine response, which I see in toast. 
But nothing change in `textView`. UI does not update… why? I do not know what to do. I used Broadcast Receiver. lost a lot of time. It does not work… Help me, please, anybody.

Comment: is userEmail public/private or none of this?

Comment: userEmail is public.

Comment: Did you check the log? It may throws an exception on get birthday. Could you comment the line: "String birthday..."?

Comment: Log is ok. graphObject: {"email":"blogpost8827@i.ua","name":"Sergey Blogpost","first_name":"Sergey","last_name":"Blogpost","gender":"male","id":"294797137557593"}, error: null}

Comment: FB answer has not field "birthday". It should throws an exception in getString("birthday"), goes to catch section and skips the setText statement. I don't know why you don't see the exception at log. You can replace getString("birthday") by optString("birthday") and it should work. But String birthday will be null.

Comment: @Alexey FB answer has field "birthday"! But my request  did't get birthday. It is correct for get it: params.putString("fields", "birthday");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FB answer has field "birthday"! But my request did't get birthday. It is correct for get it: params.putString("fields", "birthday")

```
params.putString("fields","email,birthday,picture.type(large)");
```

2) To surround with try catch all operation with JSONObject:

```
              try {
                    userModel.setEmail( data.getString("email"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    userModel.setEmail("");
                }

                try {
                    userModel.setBday(data.getString("birthday"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    userModel.setBday("");
                }
```

and set "" in cath if result null;

So, now my request looks like:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("fields", "email,birthday,picture.type(large)");

      new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),  "/me/", params,      HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public ImageLoader imageLoader;
                        public ImageView mImageView;
                        public UserInfo userModel;

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted( GraphResponse response) {

                                saveDataInSingletone(response);
                                profileView.setInfoToView();

                        }

                        private void saveDataInSingletone(GraphResponse response)  {
                            JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                            userModel = UserInfo.getInstance();
                            String lastName, firstName;
                            String profilePicUrl;


                            if (data.has("picture")) {
                                try {
                                    profilePicUrl = data.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                                   // getFacebookProfilePicture(profilePicUrl);

                                   // imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic);
                                   // imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                                    userModel.setAvatar(profilePicUrl);
                                    //mImageView.setImageBitmap(profilePic);
                                   // userModel.setAvatar(profilePic);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                     try {
                            userModel.setEmail( data.getString("email"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            userModel.setEmail("");
                        }

                        try {
                            userModel.setBday(data.getString("birthday"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            userModel.setBday("");
                        }}).executeAsync();
```